# getting server 500 internal error but working fine in postman

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Everything seems fine. I had checked with the JSON validator also the
type of data we are  passing is valid. However I am getting the following error

> POST http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/createData 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:2

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>
</head>
<body>
<form  name = "test_form"  method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="goodCall()" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
<script>
function goodCall() {
    //var url = http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData

    var data = {
      "productID": document.test_form.firstname.value,
      "title": document.test_form.lastname.value,
    }
    dataset = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log(typeof dataset);
    console.log(dataset);
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData",
  data: dataset,
  success: alert("your data has been sucefull posted"),
  dataType:  'application/json',
});
  };


</script>
</html>
```

my output

string

stackoverflow.html:29 
{"productID":"Mickey","title":"Mouse"}
   next i am getting the error

```
  jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData 500 (Internal Server Error)
    send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
    ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
    goodCall @ stackoverflow.html:30
    onclick @ stackoverflow.html:15
```

Comment: Did you check logs? I doubt if its working fine with postman because it is setting up and sending proper request header values. But its not working on browser because those headers are missing on it.

Comment: Currently you are not sending any data to the server with your request. The fact, that the callback parameter and your (potential) input parameter have the same name, has no influence on that!

Comment: i think i am sending data $.post if i go wrong plese help me to correct it

Answer (score 1):

More like this:

```
function goodCall() {
    var url = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001/createData"

    var data = {
      "productID": document.test_form.firstname.value,
      "title": document.test_form.lastname.value,
    }
    dataset = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log(typeof dataset);
    console.log(dataset);
    $.post(
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: sucess_func()
    );
  };
```

More info on parameters here:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

...or use the .ajax mthod:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot
you saved my day

Comment: i think  IN  $.POST  data : dataset

Comment: sorry i am getting the same error i tryed 
plese help me

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code? I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Also, you might find it helpful to use the browser developer tools (F12) to watch the request being sent (in the Network tab) - you can see there what is different to your Postman request.

Comment: POST http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
goodCall @ stackoverflow.html:30
onclick @ stackoverflow.html:15
these are the four errors which i am seeing while expanding the error

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest version of your code? Thanks

Comment: Can you change the value of `data` to `data` instead of `dataset`? I don't think you need to stringify it.

Comment: Also, change `success'` from `success: alert('blah blah'),` to `success: function() { alert('blah blah') },`

Comment: Thanks for your support  and valuble time
i have changed the following line everything works fine
contentType:  'application/json',

Comment: That wouldn't give you a 500 (Internal Server) error, but I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
function goodCall() {

    var data = {
      "productID": document.test_form.firstname.value,
      "title": document.test_form.lastname.value,
    }


    $.ajax({
      url: "http://34.201.147.118:3001/createData",
      type: "POST",    
      data: {data:data},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
                alert("your data has been sucefull posted");
            },
       error:function(err){
         alert("ERROR");
       }

     });
  };
```

Comment: i am getting error on console 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Thanks for your support  and valuble time
i have changed the following line everything works fine
contentType:  'application/json',